# P-Channel MOSFET not behaving as expected

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switches

I bought some IRFD9024 p-channel MOSFETs, and for some reason there seems to be a diode drop from the SOURCE to the DRAIN. As far as I understood it, the body diode is from the DRAIN to the SOURCE as illustrated by the datasheet:

[image]

To provide some context, here is my complete circuit. It uses a push button to short the capacitor, after which the voltage slowly increases again, providing a chosen amount of time for the regulator to deliver 5V to a microcontroller.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJmV59.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Your circuit looks correct, other than the strain on the switch and cap when you push on the switch (I recommend a 100 to 1000 ohm resistor in series with the switch).  Double-check that you haven't hooked the part up backwards, and that your supplier hasn't accidentally (or negligently, if it's eBay or some other shady source) supplied you with N-channel FETs.

Comment: What is your actual question? The body diode is BETWEEN drain and source. Also can you be clear about which FET you are using?

Comment: I have not really worked with P-channel MOSFETs aside from in theory, that's why I'm asking. So my question I suppose is, "am I missing something obvious here?".

As for the part, I will upload a picture shortly. I acquired it from my local electronics shop (not sure where they get it from). The datasheet I've posted is the one they used on their website.

Comment: The chip reads: IRFD A6I*RW5 9024. It looks exactly like the one in the datasheet

Comment: What makes you **think** the body diode is reversed? How does your circuit behave differently than what you expect?

Comment: @Elliot Alderson The regulator is always on with a diode drop from the 9V rail to it's input. When using a multimeter a diode drop of 0.6V can be verified from the source to the drain.

Comment: What's the voltage on the PMOS gate when you see 0.6V drop? How much current is flowing?

Comment: I'd suggest you have Drain and Source transposed if it is the correct P-Channel FET. The only way to get the regulator always on and a 0.6V drop is to have a forward biased diode in the circuit.

Comment: Okay so after some testing it appears that the device behaves exactly like an N-Channel MOSFET when connected as a low side switch. Swapping the source and gate in the above circuit results in the regulator's output slowly rising to 5V, which further confirms that it's an N-Channel. What's strange though is that I can't find documentation for it. @Tim Wescott was right, dodgy part. Won't be buying from this supplier again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Swapping source and gate would not make it work.

Comment: My apologies, I meant source and drain. Not gate.

Comment: Sounds wierd. Specially if it has the right markings in the housing.